# case statement in having clause in sql

Tags: sql

Can I have a case statement in a `HAVING` clause in SQL server 2005?

Below is my `HAVING` statement. It is giving me a syntax error.

```
@CLIENTPK_NEW IS NULL OR 
    (
        CLIENT.OH_PK = @CLIENTPK_NEW and 
        CASE WHEN @RelatedOrgs <> '11' then CLIENT.OH_PK= @CLIENTPK_NEW
        ELSE CLIENT.OH_PK in (
            SELECT dbo.OrgHeader.OH_PK FROM dbo.OrgHeader WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN
            dbo.OrgRelatedParty WITH (NOLOCK) ON dbo.OrgHeader.OH_PK = dbo.OrgRelatedParty.PR_OH_Parent INNER JOIN
            dbo.OrgHeader AS OrgHeader_1 WITH (NOLOCK) ON dbo.OrgRelatedParty.PR_OH_RelatedParty = OrgHeader_1.OH_PK
            where OrgHeader_1.OH_PK = @CLIENTPK_NEW
        ) 
        END 
    )
}
AND (@CGNEEPK IS NULL OR CGNEE.OH_PK = @CGNEEPK) AND    
part.OP_RH_NKCommodityCode = @type
```

Thanks,

Amit

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Example (from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765(v=SQL.90).aspx)):

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
GO
SELECT JobTitle, MAX(ph1.Rate)AS MaximumRate
FROM HumanResources.Employee AS e
JOIN HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory AS ph1 
    ON e.BusinessEntityID = ph1.BusinessEntityID
GROUP BY JobTitle
HAVING (MAX(CASE WHEN Gender = 'M' 
        THEN ph1.Rate 
        ELSE NULL END) > 40.00
     OR MAX(CASE WHEN Gender  = 'F' 
        THEN ph1.Rate  
        ELSE NULL END) > 42.00)
ORDER BY MaximumRate DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I have added the piece of code which is giving me syntax error and i can't figure out what is wrong with it. Please advise

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that is valid syntax. However, [the text, image, and ntext data types cannot be used in a `HAVING` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx).

**Update:** Your updated example does not make sense. Either `CLIENT.OH_PK=@CLIENTPK_NEW` or it doesn't, the rest of the statement is irrelevent, unless you use an `OR`. Perhaps you can explain the busingess logic?

Answer (score -1):

another example from [here..](http://codechef4u.com/post/2015/04/08/having-clause-with-case-expression)

```
SELECT EmployeeName ,Country,CompanyPlant,Gender, Total=MAX(PayScale)
FROM Employee
GROUP BY EmployeeName ,Country,CompanyPlant,Gender
HAVING (MAX(CASE WHEN Gender = 'Male'
 THEN PayScale
 ELSE NULL END) > 150.00
 OR MAX(CASE WHEN Gender = 'Female'
 THEN PayScale
 ELSE NULL END) > 180.00)
```